# Cron tabs in host

Tags: php, cron

My host provides a GUI that allows me to run a script at times i like.
I'm fairly new to cron and such. I'm not sure what these arguments are. And what they mean with it. I was hoping someone could explain for me.

[image]

Comment: Please use some cloud host server. It make more controll and easy to use...

Comment: For the "style" you can use https://crontab.guru/ Not sure which other parts you are wondering about.

Comment: I just dont know what "with arguments" mean. Right after the script path you can specify an arguments, whats an example of something you could put here @user3783243

Comment: If your script isn't using http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php you don't need any. (I think, I've never seen this interface before)

Comment: It's a Plesk interface, i think its a newer one too. First time for me too working with it. But good to know about the reserved variables. I am indeed not using any